# Ask for a password to show a page

Tags: html, node.js

I've made a very simple website with 1 page (main.html) just to put my Curriculum Vitae.

But to avoid all people seeing it I just want to ask for a password (i dont even need a username).

Is there a simple way to do this? It can be something like an alert asking for a password or something like that.

I'm trying this:

```
//Init App
const app = express();

//Auth
var preAuth = require('http-auth');
var basic = preAuth.basic({
        realm: "Restricted Access. Please login to proceed."
    }, function (username, password, callback) { 
         callback( (username === "user" && password === "password"));
    }
);
app.use(preAuth.connect(basic));

//View Engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', engines.mustache);
app.set('view engine','html');

//Home route
app.get('/', function (req,res) {
  res.render('main');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try it this way to see if it works correctly

```
// Authentication module.
var express = require('express');
var httpAuth = require('http-auth');
var authentication = httpAuth.basic({
    realm: "Type your username and password."
}, (username, password, callback) => {
    callback(username == 'root' && password.trim() == 'toor');
});

var app = express();
app.use(httpAuth.connect(authentication));

// Setup route.
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`Hello from express - ${req.user}!`);
});

app.listen(3030);
```

The session data would be "root" (as a user) and "toor" (as a password).

> Apparently the problem is the way you are using for the implementation of **http-auth**